# Construct a vector with sum of all elements to be 1

Tags: matlab, vector

I am looking for a quick way to construct a vector of size n.

The sum of all its elements must be 1.

For example if n = 5 the vector should be v = [0.1 0.3 0.03 0.07 0.5].

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Besides the sum beeing one, the vector has random elements?

Comment: Yes, they are randomly generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple possibility is

```
v=rand(5,1); v=v/sum(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create the vector and normalise it:

```
v = v ./ sum(v);
```